# Prove that the degree of the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ is a power of $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

> $\textbf{Question.}$ Let $n$  a positive integer and let be $K = \mathbb{Q}[a_1, \cdots, a_n]$ where $a_i$ is such that $a_i^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ for each $i = 1, \cdots, n$. Given $b \in K$, prove that the degree of the minimal polynomial $p_b(x)$ of $b$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is a power of $2$.

I would like a hint to start to solve this problem, because I don't have ideas how to start it.

Comment: [Avoiding “no clue” questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933).

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Thanks Alex for mentioning it here. I will keep this in mind while asking question here in future. This makes sense.

Comment: Are you familiar with the law calculating the extension degree of a tower of extensions?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, yes, I am.

Comment: Great! Can you show that $[K:\Bbb{Q}]$ is a power of two? By induction on $n$.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco, I'm really don't know how to start think this problem, but I'll keep in mind this topic that you linked and the tips that are in this topic in the next time that I'm going to post something, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I think so.

Induction base ($n = 1$):

I know that $x^2 - a_1^2 \in \mathbb{Q}[a_1][X]$ is a polynomial that is divided by the minimal polynomial $p_{a_1}(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$, then the degree of  $p_{a_1}(x)$ is $1$ or $2$, then

$$[\mathbb{Q}[a_1] \ : \ \mathbb{Q}] =  2^m, \ m = 0 \ \text{or} \ 1$$

Hypothesis by induction: $[ \mathbb{Q}[a_1, \cdots, a_n] \ : \ \mathbb{Q} ]$.

Comment: Correct! If you copy/paste that into the question body, it should appease Alex Francisco and other critics.

Comment: By the tower of extensions,

$[ \mathbb{Q}[a_1, \cdots, a_n, b] \ : \ \mathbb{Q} ] = [ \mathbb{Q}[a_1, \cdots, a_n, b] \ : \ \mathbb{Q}[a_1, \cdots, a_n] ] \ \cdot \ [ \mathbb{Q}[a_1, \cdots, a_n] \ : \ \mathbb{Q} ]$

By Induction hypothesis, $[ \mathbb{Q}[a_1, \cdots, a_n] \ : \ \mathbb{Q} ] = 2^m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, then I just need to prove that $[ \mathbb{Q}[a_1, \cdots, a_n, b] \ : \ \mathbb{Q}[a_1, \cdots, a_n] ]$ is a power of $2$ and I'll have that I wanted. Am I right until here? I'll think of how to show what is missing

Comment: Because $b\in K$ we have $\Bbb{Q}(b)\subseteq K$. What does the tower law tell you about $\Bbb{Q}\subseteq \Bbb{Q}(b)\subseteq K$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I will be happy if you post your hints to I accept your answer and close this topic.

Comment: Thanks, but I would rather you post the material. In a case like this I derive more pleasure from trying to make somebody else see the light. Admittedly it does not mesh very well with the site software (I have been criticized for this), but old habits ...

Comment: Ok, I posted my own question and I'll accept it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would like to thanks Jyrki Lahtonen by the hints given in the comments of my OP and which enabled me to answer my own question.

Following the hints of Jyrki Lahtonen, I start by induction proving that $[ \mathbb{Q}[a_1, \cdots, a_n] : \mathbb{Q} ] = 2^m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Induction Base ($n = 1$):

Let be $a_1$ such that $a_1^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $K := \mathbb{Q}(a_1)$. Since $a_1^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$, we know that $f(x) := x^2 - a_1^2 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ and $a_1$ is a root of $f$, then the minimal polynomial $p_{a_1}(x)$ divides f(x), therefore $p_{a_1}(x)$ has degree $1$ or $2$, i.e.,

$$[\mathbb{Q}(a_1) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2^m, m = 0 \ \text{or} \ 1$$

Supposing that $[\mathbb{Q} (a_1, \cdots, a_n) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2^m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_i^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ for each $i = 1,\cdots, n + 1$ we observe that

$$[\mathbb{Q}(a_1, \cdots, a_{n+1}) : \mathbb{Q}(a_1, \cdots, a_n)] = 2^p, p = 0 \ \text{or} \ 1,$$

by the same argument used in base step, just redefining $f(x) := x^2 - a_{n+1}^2$. By the tower of extensions and induction hypothesis, we know that

$$[\mathbb{Q}(a_1, \cdots, a_{n+1}) : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(a_1, \cdots, a_{n+1}) : \mathbb{Q}(a_1, \cdots, a_n)] \cdot [\mathbb{Q}(a_1, \cdots, a_n) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2^p \cdot 2^m = 2^{p + m},$$

then the induction proof is complete.

Following another hint of Jyrki Lahtonen, we observe that $\mathbb{Q}(b) \subset K$, because $b \in K$ by the statement of the question, then $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(b) \subset K$ and

$$[K : \mathbb{Q}] = [K : \mathbb{Q}(b)] \cdot [\mathbb{Q}(b) : \mathbb{Q}]$$

by the tower of the extensions, but observe that $x - b$ is a minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ because $b \in K$, this imply that $[K : \mathbb{Q}(b)] = \text{degree(x - b)} = 1$, so

$$[\mathbb{Q}(b) : \mathbb{Q}] = [K : \mathbb{Q}] = 2^m, \ m \in \mathbb{N}$$

by the statement proved by induction, but this means that the degree of a minimal polynomial of $b$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $2^m$, i.e., is a power of $2$. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the minimal polynomial of $a_{i+1}$ over $\Bbb{Q}[a_1,...,a_i]$.  It divides $x^2-a_{i+1}^2\in\Bbb{Q}[x]$ and so must have degree $1$ or $2$.  But this means the degree of $\Bbb{Q}[a_1,...,a_i,a_{i+1}]$ over $\Bbb{Q}[a_1,...,a_i]$ is $1$ or $2$.  Thus, if the degree of $\Bbb{Q}[a_1,...,a_i]$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ is a power of $2$, say $2^j$, then the degree of $\Bbb{Q}[a_1,...,a_i,a_{i+1}]$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ is the product of the degree of $\Bbb{Q}[a_1,...,a_i,a_{i+1}]$ over $\Bbb{Q}[a_1,...,a_i]$ and that of $\Bbb{Q}[a_1,...,a_i]$ over $\Bbb{Q}$, and is thus $2^j$ or $2^{j+1}$, in either case a power of $2$. By induction, then, the degree of $\Bbb{Q}[a_1,...,a_n]$ over $\Bbb{Q}$is a power of $2$.